# The import java.awt.BorderLayout cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

I created a new Java project on Eclipse and got the `The import java.awt.BorderLayout cannot be resolved` error. What went wrong and how do I fix this?

I created a new JFrame from WindowsBuilder and the default code generated was:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout; //error here
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class frameGUI extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    frameGUI frame = new frameGUI();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public frameGUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0)); //error here
        setContentPane(contentPane);
    }

}
```

I'm also getting a `BorderLayout cannot be resolved to a type` error.

Comment: check whether you have that library in your build path

Comment: @ArunSai AWT is included in Java

Comment: Do you have a `module-info.java`, and if so, does it include `requires java.desktop;`?

Comment: Yes, I have a ```module-info.java``` and included ```requires java.desktop;``` in it.

Comment: Can you update your question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Mark Rotteveel said it all. Move that import to the end, to see whether there are other import problems. If you are using something like maven or gradle, do a reload. It might be that not all modules are loaded.

Comment: @JoopEggen `java.awt.BorderLayout` is in the system library.

Comment: Please show which system library do you have in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_ in the tab _Libraries_ and also which Java installation is used to resolve that _JRE System Library_ by showing what you have configured in the preferences _Java > Installed JREs_. It might you have a higher Java version that is supported by your Eclipse version or a Java without the full system library.

Comment: I have a ```JRE system library [JavaSE-16]``` in Java Build Path. As for Installed JREs, I have ```Java SE 16.0.2 [16.0.2]``` selected.

Comment: In _Installed JREs_ what's the installation/home directory of `Java SE 16.0.2 [16.0.2]`? What you get for that Java when you run `<Java SE 16.0.2 [16.0.2] home>/bin/java -version` on the command line? Which Eclipse version?

Comment: It looks like your code is in the default, unnamed package. IIRC (but I'm not 100% sure), you can't use the module system in combination with the unnamed package. Move your code to a package.

Answer (score 0):

@Mark Rotteveel answered: It looks like your code is in the default, unnamed package. IIRC (but I'm not 100% sure), you can't use the module system in combination with the unnamed package. Move your code to a package.